# Allow the selection of multiple images in NetlifyCMS

Tags: gatsby, netlify-cms

I am currently integrating NetlifyCMS into my Gatsby project and I am stuck allowing the selection of multiple images. I didn't specify any media library as I just want to store those images directly in my repo. I am using `gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms` and use this config for my collection

```
- name: "post"
    label: "Posts"
    label_singular: "Post"
    folder: "example/data/posts"
    create: true
    slug: "{{year}}-{{month}}-{{day}}-{{slug}}"
    editor:
      preview: false
    fields:
      - { label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string" }
      - label: "Media"
        name: "media"
        widget: "image"
        allow_multiple: true
        media_library:
          config:
            multiple: true
      - { label: "Location", name: "location", type: "Point", widget: "map", required: false }
      - { label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "text", required: false }
```

Although I specified `allow_multiple` and `media_library.config.multiple` I am not able to select more than one image in the NetlifyCMS admin GUI.

I have those packages installed

```
netlify-cms@^2.10.17
netlify-cms-app@^2.11.14
netlify-cms-widget-image@^2.5.0
gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms@^4.1.39
```

Did I miss anything? Didn't find anything about that in the docs.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to add a third party media library to support this.

Comment: And you didn't say anything about what it was or anything, so no value to anyone else.